# I2C - addressing

Tags: microcontroller, i2c, texas-instruments

In the i2c protocol, I would like to know how the slave & master address are assigned. Most of the internet doc talk about how the protocol work, but i wasn't able to find doc about i2c slave & master addressing.

For instance, I want to communicate between my tm4c129 LP and a SparkFun light sensor [datasheet](https://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/TSL256x.pdf). In the tivaware [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spmu296/spmu296.pdf) ( TI drivers), they set the master address as 0x3B.

Could I set an other legal address for that master device?

Same goes for the light sensor, the datasheet refer the device address has either 0x39 , 0x29 or 0x49? Can i change the slave address or it is build in the IC of the PCB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The I<sup>2</sup>C address is set within the chip itself. There may be pins exposed to select an alternate address within a range, but there is no way to give it a completely different range short of reimplementing it from scratch.

Comment: And I guess, you need to pay Phillips to have an address? Also, if you have the same device multiple times and you want to connect all of them on the same i2c bus, you would need some sort of Demux to communicate with the right one?

Comment: You need a licence to create hardware that implements I2C, but you can take any address you like (although using a common address will gain you no favor among system designers). A I2C hub can be used to split a single I2C bus into multiple virtual buses, each with its own isolated address space.

Comment: One note, as an I2C master in a single master system, the master address is pretty much irrelevant.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams You may need a license to use the term "I2C" but many companies have adopted the name "two wire protocol" or "two wire interface" and implement I2C without encumbrance from NXP.

Comment: @MathieuL you do not have to pay anyone for an address; there is no standards body which maintains a database of addresses. You pick an address that is unlikely to conflict with other I2C devices you might share the bus with.

Comment: @MathieuL - with 7 bit addressing, there are only 127 (don't use 0000000b) possible addresses. Obviously, each device cannot have a unique address.

Comment: I2C address conflicts are a common problem.  Recently, Linear Technology came out with [LTC4316](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC4316), which is an I2C address translator IC.